# high dimensional outlier detection using python

Tags: python, pca, anomaly-detection

Can someone please point me to a robust python implementation of algorithms like Robust-PCA or Angle Based Outlier detection (ABOD)? I tried a couple of python implementations of Robust-PCA, but they turned out to be very memory-intensive, and the program crashed. My dataset is 60,000 X 900 floats. R has an implementation of ABOD, but I want to stick to python.

Answer (score 1):

Outliers detection is verry important, there are plenty of research publications dealing with it.
The scalability of density based algorithm is not really performant.
I used PCA for reducing dimension, and the local outlier factor method.

You can find a well implemented version for massive data at : 
https://github.com/damjankuznar/pylof/blob/master/lof.py

HTH

Comment: Also worth mentioning that this is implemented is the current release of `scikit learn`: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html